# Building a decorator with three parameters - closure not working in Python 2.x

Tags: python

```
def ensure_type(parameter_name, the_type, type_converter_fn=None):
   def decorator(fn):
      def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):

         if not type_converter_fn: # fails here
            type_converter_fn = the_type

         return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
      return wrapped
   return decorator
```

When stepping through the `wrapped` function the `parameter_name` and `the_type` closure variables are correctly bound but `type_converter_fn` is not. This happens regardless of whether `ensure_type` is called with or without that optional parameter and it also happens if I make the parameter mandatory.

Why do the first two parameters work whilst the third never gets assigned?

For reference, I get an exception on this line - `if not type_converter_fn` saying that it has been referenced before assignment.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  At least the last three lines are off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scoping in Python is determined statically.  An assignment inside a function makes a variable local to that function.  You cannot access a local variable before its first assignment.

The second line in

```
if not type_converter_fn:
    type_converter_fn = the_type
```

makes `type_converter_fn` local to `wrapped()`, so the access in the first line of this snippet yields an `UnboundLocalError`.  (BTW, it would have been so much easier if you would have told us what error message you got and in which line.  Always copy the full traceback of the error message into your question -- it saves answerers a lot of time.)

Comment: That's excellent - thank you. Will grab the traceback in future.

Answer (score 2):

Your "action levels" are too complicated. Just deal with stuff as soon as you have access to it.

As

```
if not isinstance(parameter_name, str):
    raise Exception("parameter_name must be a string")

if not type_converter_fn:
    type_converter_fn = the_type
```

only deals with "outer" parameters, you should do it there.

The same applies to

```
arg_position = list(fn.func_code.co_varnames).index(parameter_name) - 1
```

for one level deeper.

In general, I would do (untested!):

```
def ensure_type(parameter_name, the_type, type_converter_fn=None):
    if not isinstance(parameter_name, str):
        raise Exception("parameter_name must be a string")

    if not type_converter_fn:
        type_converter_fn = the_type

    def decorator(fn):
        arg_position = list(fn.func_code.co_varnames).index(parameter_name) - 1 #minus once because of self
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if arg_position > -1:
                the_arg = args[arg_position]
                if the_arg is not None and not isinstance(the_arg, the_type):
                    all_the_args = list(args)
                    all_the_args[arg_position] = type_converter_fn(the_arg)
                    args = tuple(all_the_args)
            return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

EDIT: As I just see: it is still too complicated.

Wrapping should only happen if needed. `if arg_position < 0`, you could either raise an exception (because the whole stuff is pointless then, so use `.find()` instead of `.index()`), or you could return the original `fn`.

```
def ensure_type(parameter_name, the_type, type_converter_fn=None):
    if not isinstance(parameter_name, str):
        raise Exception("parameter_name must be a string")
    if not type_converter_fn:
        type_converter_fn = the_type

    def decorator(fn):
        arg_position = list(fn.func_code.co_varnames).index(parameter_name) - 1 #minus once because of self
        # Either use .find() here, or live with -1 and return the original function then:
        if arg_position < 0: # only needed with .index()
            return fn
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            the_arg = args[arg_position]
            if the_arg is not None and not isinstance(the_arg, the_type):
                all_the_args = list(args)
                all_the_args[arg_position] = type_converter_fn(the_arg)
                args = tuple(all_the_args)
            return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```